# Safari placing period (fullstop) on selected option in form select?

Tags: html, css, forms

I'm creating a select form and stripped most styles so far, but I'm noticing this weird behavior on safari where the currently selected option has a `.` before the text in the dropdown. To clarify, if I have a yes/no select with a standard value of yes, if i click the arrow, when the drop down is revealed it says `.yes / no`

Does anyone know why this may be happening and how to remove it?

**Markup**

```html
<select>
    <option value="1">inexperienced</option>
    <option value="2">experienced</option>
</select>
```

[image]

Comment: Are all elements closed correctly? Can you post you're markup here?

Comment: See above, for this specific select box, i get `.inexperienced` as the first option in the drop down, however the `.` is only visible in the dropdown, and not in the area where selected text shows (what's that called? placeholder?)

Comment: Looks fine in Safari. Which version are you using? Is there any pseudo-element (`:before` or `:after`) attached to the `select`-element or the first `option`-element?

Comment: @insertusernamehere no there are not, I'm using safari 8.0. If i switch the selected option, the `.` moves to the front of that word instead. In example if i switch from inexperienced to experienced, the drop down now shows `inexperienced / .experienced`

Comment: This isn't happening on other websites, only your own? And only in Safari? Do you have a [user style sheet](http://webdesign.about.com/od/css/ht/htcssusersafari.htm) for Safari on your machine?

Comment: @MrLister no, only mine. I do not have a user style sheet for safari. I know for a fact the `.` is related to the selected element as it switches based on which one is selected.